# File name on the basis of cell value in vlookup

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

Currently, I am using vlookup as per the below:

This is in Cell M3 of main book:

```
=VLOOKUP(L3,'C:\Users\vp\Desktop\xcl\day_data\[5460993.csv]5460993'!$A:$C,3,0)
```

The value in Cell Z3 of the main book is ***5460993***

My excel where we vlookup is dynamic and it depends on Cell Z3.

I tried:

```
=VLOOKUP(L3,'C:\Users\vp\Desktop\xcl\day_data\['H3'.csv]'H3''!$A:$C,3,0)
```

it gave the error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOgYd.png)

Comment: I've had the same error today and checked this post: ( https://windowsreport.com/problem-formula-excel/ ). hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDIRECT:

`=VLOOKUP(L3,"'C:\Users\vp\Desktop\xcl\day_data\[" & Z3&".csv]" & Z3&"'!$A:$C" ,3,0)`